# print_r result of mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi guys recently I am struggling with an output of my sql query result. After doing the query and the loop. The output shows like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 68686.4792
            [Average] => 68686.4792
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 83703.3284
            [Average] => 83703.3284
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 95899.7763
            [Average] => 95899.7763
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 115881.2429
            [Average] => 115881.2429
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 99444.4138
            [Average] => 99444.4138
        )

)
```

but what I expected is the output with this format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 68686.4792


    [1] => 83703.3284


    [2] => 95899.7763


    [3] => 115881.2429


    [4] => 99444.4138


)
```

And here is my php code:

```
<?php

     $strQuery1 = 'SELECT Avg(Price) as Average From price GROUP by year(Date_of_Transfer)';
     $result1 = $dbhandle->query($strQuery1) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");
     $rows=array();
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
     $rows[] = $row;
  }
     echo'<pre>';
     print_r ($rows);
     echo'</pre>';

?>
```

I wonder if i did something wrong in coding or is there any way that i can converted the array to the format I expected. Thank you.

Comment: Try `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
     $rows[] = $row['0'];
  }`

Comment: oh thank you so much ! It works!

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference between yours and mine. A little bit confused, thank you so much

Comment: also try `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){ $rows[] = $row['Average']; }`

Comment: Thank you! It also works! But i am just a little bit confused how can this works! Thank you.

Comment: Oops... @Tamil Selvan C 's answer is better than mine! I dunno why the fetched result contains two rows...  I just found that you want an array instead of an array of array... The difference between yours and mine is that my answer accepts the specified column only but yours accepts the all fetched result no matter what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

The options here are very simple you either flatten the array or do your foreach loop one step into the array.

**SOLUTION 1:**

```
// $array = your multidimensional array

$flat_array = array();

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $k=>$v){

$flat_array[$k] = $v;

}
```

Also documented: http://www.phpro.org/examples/Flatten-Array.html

**SOLUTION 2:**
This has been mentioned by other people that have answered already

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){ $rows[] = $row['0']; }
```